# Symfony3 FOS UserBundle how to load choice as entity

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I am using Symfony3.1 with FOS UsersBundle and I want some added fields to be loaded as specific Entity.

In `RegistrationType` I have

```
->add('country', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'label' => 'label.country',
    'required' => false,
    'placeholder' => 'label.select_country',
    'choices'  => array(
        'France' => '7v8tqr',
    ),
    ))
```

In my Entity `User` I have

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country", referencedColumnName="short")
 */
protected $country;
```

I can't use the `EntityType` as it loads every available entity and I use the same kind of field for provinces and cities which are quite huge (I manage their content with javascript).

When I load a registered user, the country field is served as a Country Entity but when I register a new user or modify an existing one, I only have the string "short" which causes an error `Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\Country" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\User#$country", got "string" instead.`.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: Can you not load the EntityType in your form and only return Countries (is there a field in your database that specifies whether an entry is country, province, city, etc.)? That would seem to be the easiest method. Alternatively, in your Controller you could use the Country ID from your form to look up the Country entity before you persist the form submission.

Comment: Yes I can load the EntityType but when a user selects a country then (with javascript) I provide the corresponding list of provinces and when one is selected I provide the corresponding list of cities ortherwise the data is too big. There's a way to manage dynamic data with symfony but I've found it quite simplier to do it with js.

Comment: About looking for the ID, yes I could do it if it was "my" form submission but as I use FOS UserBundle and don't want to overwrite too much I can't check or even load the entity.

Comment: I don't have more time to look into it right now, but I think these two resources might help. You might be able to use [events](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) to lookup the entity before the form is processed. Or, you can [override](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html) the FoS controller (not directly in the vendor bundle, but within your app).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a look at events to try to avoid overriding controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mcriecken who led me in the right direction, I have implemented the following solution, using an EventListener

in `services.yml`

```
app_user.registration:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\UserRegistrationListener
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

and the EventListener `UserRegistrationListener.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class UserRegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm()->getData();

        //Gets the locations
        $form->setCountry($this->getCountry($form->getCountry()));
        $form->setProvince($this->getProvince($form->getProvince()));
        $form->setCity($this->getCity($form->getCity()));
    }

    //Loads the country as an entity
    public function getCountry($short)
    {
        if ($short == null) return null;

        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Country');
        return $repository->findOneByShort($short);
    }

    //Loads the province as an entity
    public function getProvince($short)
    {
        if ($short == null) return null;

        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Province');
        return $repository->findOneByShort($short);
    }

    //Loads the city as an entity
    public function getCity($short)
    {
        if ($short == null) return null;

        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:City');
        return $repository->findOneByShort($short);
    }

}
```

Then at the end my FOS User object contains COuntry, Province and City as Objects and it can be saved to DB :-)